# Oregon Trail Card Game Oxen

Tags: the-oregon-trail-card-game

I'm confused about how oxen work in this game. For example, the calamity card for Bad Water states that if I get 2 bad water cards in a round, then my oxen die. Is the number of oxen I have based on the number of oxen supply cards the team has, or do I have a specific number of oxen innately that can be replaced with oxen supply cards?

Answer (score 1):

Your oxen count is not based on the number of supply cards you have - it is as you mentioned that you just have an automatic 2 oxen.  When calamity cards affect your oxen they will just affect/kill all of them, and a single oxen supply card can save you from being stranded without new ones.